# spring unit testing controller not resolving WebAppContext

Tags: spring

I have read online tutorials on unit testing spring MVC, I have copied from tutorials but `WebAppContext.class` never resolves as a type. What should this resolve too?

```
package com.doyleisgod.springmavenexample.controllers;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import java.util.Arrays;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.model;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class, WebAppContext.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class HomeControllerTest {
       private MockMvc mockMvc;
       @Test
        public void indexTest() {

            mockMvc.perform(get("/index.htm", 1L))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(view().name("index"))
                    .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp"));

        }
}
```

Eclipse shows `WebAppContext cannot be resolved to a type`

How do i fix this?

Comment: Yo your own configuration class..

Comment: What configuration does it need? isnt this a standard class? or cant it pick up config from my xml files.

Comment: No it isn't a standard class, else it would resolve. Maybe you should read on how spring with unit testing works and what the `@ContextConfiguration` actually does.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to 
org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext; or
org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

You need spring-test dependencies to resolve these.